# How to reference a Player in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The code (GameObject reference) doesn't show up so I need a different way to reference a player. I have not tried much though.

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CamaraBehaviour : MonoBehaviour {
    public Object Player;
    public float yOffset = 3.0f;
    public float zOffset = 10.0f;
    Vector3 newPos = Player.transform.position;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        newPos.y = newPos.y + yOffset;
        newPos.z = newPos.z + zOffset;
        transform.position = newPos;
        transform.LookAt(player.transform);
    }
}
```

This is my camera fixing code. Which is why I need the reference in the first place.
I thank you for the help (NO gmae written please the school blocks the word so if you reply with the word I wont be able to access the site).

Comment: its GameObject not Object for the type for Player

Answer (score 2):

The `Player` does not show up in the inspector because it's type, `Object` is not serializable. You want to use `GameObject` for Unity objects.

```cs
public GameObject Player;
```

You have a few other errors in this code.

1. You can't set the `newPos` using a reference to another object outside of a method. Do this in `Update()` instead.

   ```cs
   Vector3 newPos;

   // Update is called once per frame
   void Update () {
       newPos = Player.transform.position;
       // your other code
   }
   ```
2. There is a typo on the last line of update, where the P in Player needs to be capital (that's what you named your variable).

   ```cs
   transform.LookAt(Player.transform);
   ```

EDIT: However, since you only seem to be using the Player.transform anyways, you might as well go ahead and reference the transform component instead.

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CamaraBehaviour : MonoBehaviour {
    public Transform Player;
    public float yOffset = 3.0f;
    public float zOffset = 10.0f;
    Vector3 newPos;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        newPos = Player.position;
        newPos.y = newPos.y + yOffset;
        newPos.z = newPos.z + zOffset;
        transform.position = newPos;
        transform.LookAt(Player.position);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the script is attached to the player you can do this:

```cs
private GameObject player;

void Start()
{
    player = GetComponent<GameObject>();
}
```

However, you can make a public variable as demonstrated in the other answer by Marcus.

But... If you want to find the game object at runtime, you can also do this:

```cs
private GameObject player;

void Start()
{
    player = GameObject.FindWithTag("Player");
}
```

You just have to be certain to tag your player accordingly.

Comment: I weep inside every time I see `GameObject.FindWithTag` somewhere. It's unnecessarily costly and too easy to make better:

`public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
 public static Player instance { get; private set; }
 void OnEnable ()
 {
  instance = this;
 }
 void OnDisable ()
 {
  instance = null;
 }
}`

(also make sure this class is executed early in "Project Settings/Script Execution Order")

then you replace every `GameObject.FindWithTag` with just `Player.instance`

Comment: I'm familiar with the Singleton, and you are 100% correct. I agree with you, but is the O.P. ready for this lesson yet? @AndrewŁukasik Your suggestion 'here' should be an answer, in my opinion.

Comment: Good point sir, it might be something little over the head for newcomers

Comment: You've provided useful research material for him. We all have to start somewhere, and even though he may not use it now, you've presented a pretty solid future when he is ready. ;)